# Navigate HTML Tags to Extract text from Anchored Tags

Tags: python, web-scraping

I need to extract the certain text from a web page but the anchor tags where the text is located is embedded in several subclasses.

I am new to web-scraping so apologies if this scenario was already answered but I have need to scrape text from this webpage (https://www.astm.org/search/fullsite-search.html?query=alloy&toplevel=products-and-services&sublevel=standards-and-publications), I've tried using bs4 to parse the page but when creating a soup object I am unable to get to the tags from each separate result.

Using requests and bs4 I have tried

```py
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text)
    print(soup)
```

and it outputs the tags where the text I need is found

```html
    <div class ="span8 main searchresults">
    <div id="results"></div>
```

I was expecting to see the tags that are within the results id which should look like

```html
    <div id="results">
    <div class="res">
    <div class="resTable">
    <h4 class="resTitle>
    <a...
```

I need to get the title text from each result, for example the first text would be

```py
    "ASTM A506-16 Standard Specification for Alloy and Structural Alloy Steel, Sheet and Strip, Hot-Rolled and Cold-Rolled"
```

The problem is when I try to reference any of these tags within bs4 nothing is returned. How do I go through these classes to get to the text within the  tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data seem encoded in HTML page in JSON format (BeautifulSoup won't help you there, but you can extract the data with the `re` module):

```
import re
import json
import requests
from pprint import pprint

url = 'https://www.astm.org/search/fullsite-search.html?query=alloy&toplevel=products-and-services&sublevel=standards-and-publications'

data = json.loads(re.findall(r'var mc_results = ({.*?})\s*;', requests.get(url, verify=False).text, flags=re.DOTALL)[0])

for s in data['resSet']:
    for result in s['results']:
        pprint(result['res']['meta'])
        print('*' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
{'gs_designation': 'A506',
 'gs_homebook': '0103 CS01',
 'gs_year': '16',
 'mc_addtocart': 'PDF-A506',
 'mc_date': '2016',
 'mc_dltype': 'allstd,active,basecompass',
 'mc_doctype': 'Active Standard',
 'mc_doi': 'A0506-16',
 'mc_icsdata': '77.140.50 (Flat steel products and semi-products)',
 'mc_keywordsen': 'cold-rolled steel products~ hot-rolled steel products~ ',
 'mc_language': 'English',
 'mc_login': 'true',
 'mc_maincat': 'standard,sedl',
 'mc_maincomm': 'A01',
 'mc_relatedurl': 'A506_related.htm',
 'mc_section': '01',
 'mc_sectors': 'Metals',
 'mc_sublevel': 'standards-and-publications,sedl-digital-library',
 'mc_suburl': '/SUBSCRIPTION/filtrexx40.cgi?+/usr6/htdocs/newpilot.com/SUBSCRIPTION/REDLINE_PAGES/A506.htm',
 'mc_tax0': 'Properties_and_Measurements,Test_Methods,Materials',
 'mc_tax1': 'Chemical_Properties,Mechanical_Test,Metals_--_Iron_and_Alloys',
 'mc_tax2': 'Chemical_Composition,Fractography,Tensile_Test,Steel,Iron_and_Steel_Products',
 'mc_tax3': 'Hardness_Test,Alloy_Steel,Flat_Products,Specialty_Steel',
 'mc_tax4': 'Structural_Steel',
 'mc_taxkeywordsen': 'Alloy Steel,Flat Products,Structural Steel,Chemical '
                     'Composition,Hardness Test,Tensile Test',
 'mc_tertiary': 'standards-products',
 'mc_toplevel': 'products-and-services',
 'mc_unspscdata': '30264100(Steel alloy sheets)',
 'title': 'Standard Specification for Alloy and Structural Alloy Steel, Sheet '
          'and Strip, Hot-Rolled and Cold-Rolled'}
********************************************************************************
{'gs_designation': 'B768',
 'gs_homebook': '0201 CS02',
 'gs_year': '11(2016)',
 'mc_addtocart': 'PDF-B768',
 'mc_date': '2016',
 'mc_dltype': 'allstd,active,basecompass',
 'mc_doctype': 'Active Standard',
 'mc_doi': 'B0768-11R16',

...and so on.
```

Comment: Thank you this worked for me, can you explain how you knew the data was in json and how you accessed it?

Comment: @jgonz1 I didn't find anything with beautifulsoup so I looked at the source code of HTML page in Firefox developer tools. There I searched for the data I saw on the rendered page. The data is in `<script>` tag, so I know it's JSON...and I can use `re` to extract it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did to drill into the different classes

## load into beautifulsoup

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, 'html.parser')
```

## find the leaderboard in the html code and parse out

```
FeaturedArticles = soup.findAll('article',{'class':'featured'})
```

print(FeaturedArticles)

```
for Articles in FeaturedArticles: 
    title = Articles.a.text
    print(title)
```